Excel - Display entry with the highest value that meets a case-sensitive condition

I have multiple Sheets and would now like to add a statistics sheet which only displays the entry with the highest competition results per sheet. That's easy. However I'd also like to display the highest scoring entry that meets certain genetic conditions. This is the part that gives me troubles as it has to be case sensitive, since A/A is vastly different from a/a (those are example values).
This is what I have right now:
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100; MATCH(MAXIFS(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100; Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100; "a/a"; Sheet1!$D$2:$D$100; "b/b"); Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100; 0))
Its working just fine except for the fact that it's not case sensitive and I don't know what I can do to make it case sensitive. The result should be "TestCase4" however it's "TestCase1" due to this. I already tried using CHAR() instead in a desperate attempt but that of course didn't work. And I can't get stuff like e.g. REGEXMATCH() or EXACT() to work in a MAXIFS.
I have now added a new column next to the genetics, that just writes down a 1 if it's a/a, 1.5 if it's A/a and a 0 if it's A/A and check for those columns in the MAXIFS clause but there has to be a nicer solution to this surely? I also would like to keep it somewhat biologically accurate so just changing the letters won't do.
Grateful for any tips!

Have you tried something like =ISNUMBER(FIND()) ?

Look into EXACT e.g. https://exceljet.net/functions/exact-function

@Excellor I can't put a row range into FIND() so I don't know how that would help?

@Ike I already said that EXACT() is probably what I need but I can't get it to work in a MAXIFS()

What's your Excel version?

@Ike usually Excel 365 but if there's only a proper solution in google table thats also fine.

If you have Excel 365 you can use FILTER
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A2:C6,EXACT("a/a",C2:C6)),2,-1),1)



This one seems to work, thank you.
I would like however to have a functioning version in Google tables as well, do you know a solution without Take? That's one of the only excel functions google doesn't (Seem to?)  have.

I never work with google sheets - but maybe use MAX instead

I found a working solution, the competition results are luckily in this format 00,000 so an identical one is quite unlikely so INDEX(MATCH(MAX(Filter()) works to get the name there. Filter is a new function for me but seems really useful, so thank you very much again!

For Google Sheets you can use =CHOOSEROWS(SORT(FILTER(A2:C6,EXACT("a/a",C2:C6)),2,-1),1) no risk of getting wrong index. But most importantly: don't tag Excel if you're looking for a Google Sheets solution. Google Sheets and Excel have some similarities, but also a lot differences.

Using EXACT, replacing MAXIFS with MAX & FILTER:
=INDEX(
    Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,
    MATCH(
        MAX(
            FILTER(
                Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,
                EXACT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100, "a/a") *
                    EXACT(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$100, "b/b"),
                ""
            )
        ),
        Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,
        0
    )
)



If there could be multiple results:
=FILTER(
    Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,
    Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100 =
        MAX(
            FILTER(
                Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,
                EXACT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100, "a/a") *
                    EXACT(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$100, "b/b"),
                ""
            )
        )
)


Update for Google Sheets
Google Sheets FILTER syntax is a bit different from Excel's:

FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])

So it works after removing the third parameter for [if_empty] (""):




This unfortunately doesn't seem to work for me? I get a area sizes(?) don't match.
I hope this is not again a "doesn't work in the german version of excel" thing ....

@Yuri, I found out why it wasn't working under Google Sheets - I had a single value ("") as the third parameter as [if empty] under Excel, resulting in area size mismatch. If you have time, you may want to test the updated answer.
